# Testing protected method of AccountController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

I am testing Account Controller in asp.net mvc project. I tested all methods and I looked the code coverage results, I noticed the Initialize method is not coveraged.

How can I test this method?

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    public IFormsAuthenticationService FormsService { get; set; }
    public IMembershipService MembershipService { get; set; }

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (FormsService == null) { FormsService = new FormsAuthenticationService(); }
        if (MembershipService == null) { MembershipService = new AccountMembershipService(); }

        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
```

I tried this test method but error occured.

```
           [TestMethod]
        public void Constructor_ReturnsController()
        {
            RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(new MockHttpContext(), new RouteData());
            AccountController controller = new AccountController
            {
                FormsService = null,
                MembershipService = null,
                Url = new UrlHelper(requestContext),
            };

            IController cont = controller;
            cont.Execute(requestContext);
        }
```

Error Message:

Test method MVC3Project.Tests.Controllers.AccountControllerTests+AccountControllerTest.Constructor_ReturnsController threw exception: 
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to invoke it explicitly in your unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AccountController_Initialize_Method_Should_WireUp_Dependencies()
{
    // arrange
    AccountController controller = new AccountController();

    // act
    controller.Initialize(null);

    // assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(controller.FormsService);
    Assert.IsNotNull(controller.MembershipService);
}
```

Note that using the `Initialize` method to setup your dependencies is bad practice. I would recommend you using dependency injection:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    public IFormsAuthenticationService FormsService { get; private set; }
    public IMembershipService MembershipService { get; private set; }

    public AccountController(IFormsAuthenticationService formsService, IMembershipService membershipService)
    {
        FormsService = formsService;
        MembershipService = membershipService;
    }

    ... actions
}
```

Now you could setup your favorite dependency injection framework to inject those dependencies into your controller. For example with Ninject that's pretty easy. Install the `Ninject.MVC3` NuGet and then inside the generated `~/App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs` file configure the kernel:

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IFormsAuthenticationService>().To<FormsAuthenticationService>();
    kernel.Bind<IMembershipService>().To<AccountMembershipService>();
}
```

and finally you could mock those dependencies into your unit test and then define expectations on them.